# Laravel multiple table eloquent relationship

Tags: php, laravel

I have three tables named as Users, Menu items, Category

**Users table:**

```
+-----------------------+
|       Users           |
+====+======+===========+
| id | name | type      |
+----+------+-----------+
```

**Restaurant table:**

```
+-----------------------+
|       Restaurant      |
+====+======+===========+
| id | name | user_id   |
+----+------+-----------+
```

**Menu items table:**

```
+------------------------------------------+
|       Menu_items                         |
+====+======+==============================+
| id | cat_id | user_id  |  restaurant_id  |
+----+------+------------------------------+
```

**Category table:**

```
+-----------------------+
|       categories      |
+====+======+===========+
| id | name             |
+----+------+-----------+
```

And my relationships model functions are here.

**Restaurant model**

```
class Restaurants extends Model
{
    public $table = 'restaurants';
    public function getFoodItems()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Menuitems','restaurant_id','id');
    }

    public function getCatGroup()
    {
        return $this->getFoodItems()->groupBy('main_category');
    }
}
```

**User model**

```
class Chefs extends Model
{
    public $table = 'users';

    public  function restaurants()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Restaurants::class, 'vendor_id', 'id');
    }

    public function getVendorFoodDetails()
    {
        return  $this->hasMany('App\Models\Menuitems','vendor_id','vendor_id');
    }
}
```

**Category model**

```
class Category extends Model
{
    public $table = 'categories';
    public  function menuitems()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Menuitems', 'main_category', 'id');
    }
}
```

**Menu items model**

```
class Menuitems extends Model
{
    protected $table    = "menu_items";
    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'main_category', 'id');
    }
}
```

and my response should be something like this below.

```
{
    "id": 13,
    "name": "Vendor",
    "restaurants": [
        {
            "id": 3,
            "vendor_id": 13,
            "name": "Restaurant Name",
            "get_cat_group": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "main_category": 1,
                    "categories": {
                        "id": 1,
                        "name": "test11111",
                        "menuitems": [
                            {
                                "id": 1,
                                "name": "Masala test",
                            },
                            {
                                "id": 8,
                                "name": "Masala Channa"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "id": 7,
                    "main_category": 2,
                    "categories": {
                        "id": 2,
                        "name": "tests2",
                        "menuitems": [
                            {
                                "id": 7,
                                "name": "Masala Channa"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

How should I reach this can some one please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

Use 'with' to model when select to make return object have data that you refer to

```
Restaurants::with('Menuitems')->get();
```

but if you want to [nested](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#nested-eager-loading) the relation use .(dot) in with

```
Restaurants::with('Menuitems.Categories')->get();
```